# Force ALSA/pulseaudio to use both output jacks at the same time

Tags: ubuntu, alsa, pulseaudio

I have a dodgy jack at the front of my computer. I decided to use the one that connects directly to the motherboard at the back. The problem is that from time to time the unplugged jack at the front detects that headphones have been plugged in.

What I tried to do is disable automatic switching in default.pa, which does work as intended. The problem is when the front jack erroneously detect that something is plugged in it disables the motherboard jack.

The front jack does work if you apply pressure on it. I tested the situation with two set of headphones. Indeed, when you use the back jack you get a line out device. But if, keeping the back jack in use, you plug in something in the front jack line out disappears and is replaced with headphones. This is what is happening when you leave the front jack unplugged. It erroneously detects headphones, and disables line out for a split second. Then it removes headphones, leaving me with no sound. I need to manually select line out.

I see two solutions to the problem: have both jacks enabled at the same time; disable the front jack all together. Any ideas how to do any of those things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved my own problem: disable auto mute mode in ALSA mixer. You still need to keep the automatic port switch line commented out in default.pa, otherwise the volume change indicator pops up every time the front jack detects them non-existent headphones. Currently, every 10 seconds or so.

Comment: You'll still get interrupts if the faulty front jack switch triggers. Can you completely unplug the front jack? Or cut the cable(s), if it's damaged anyway?

Comment: I don't get interrupts at all. This is because the back jack is not switched off. Something weird is going on anyway. It all works fine if you apply pressure sideways on the front jack, suggesting this is a connector problem. However, if I unplug it from the motherboard, the problem still occurs, but less frequently. Maybe it detects too low of an impedance between the audio pin and ground, I don't know really. It's too infrequent to diagnose. And when the front jack is unplugged from the motherboard, I cannot use a second set of headphones for testing.